# SimpleXML append multiple files

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to combine multiple XML files, using SimpleXML if possible. I'm just trying to append products, children, and child data from file 2 into file 1. I'm not trying to merge elements, just append file 2 to the bottom of file 1, and so on. (Though I guess this is technically merging merchandiser elements?) The files contain the same schema and will both look similar to the example below, only thing that will be changing is the actual text. This is just XML for two different products, I added a large space in between products so that it's easier to see where it ends.

```
<merchandiser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="merchandiser.xsd">
<header>
<merchantId>35928</merchantId>
<merchantName>Sunspel Clothing</merchantName>
<createdOn>01/14/2016 02:03:31</createdOn>
</header>
<product product_id="14633" name="Cotton Socks" sku_number="1588/102">
<category>
<primary>Accessories</primary>
<secondary>Men's~~Socks</secondary>
</category>
<URL>
<product>
http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=D*rqD2paIXY&offerid=191965.14633&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sunspel.com%2Fuk%2Fcotton-sock-black.html
</product>
<productImage>
http://www.sunspel.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/5/1588-102-new.jpg
</productImage>
</URL>
<description>
<short>
Our new cotton socks are designed by Sunspel and crafted in an Italian factory steeped in years of experience, skill and heritage. They are made from the highest quality, extra-long staple Egyptian cotton yarn which, prior to knitting is combed, twisted and mercerised to enhance the comfort, shine and absorption of the fabric as well as its resistance to pilling and shrinking.
</short>
</description>
<discount currency="GBP">
<type>amount</type>
</discount>
<price currency="GBP">
<retail>15.00</retail>
</price>
<shipping>
<availability>in-stock</availability>
</shipping>
<pixel>
http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=D*rqD2paIXY&bids=191965.14633&type=15&subid=0
</pixel>
</product>
<product product_id="15115" name="Cotton Socks" sku_number="1589/236">
<category>
<primary>Accessories</primary>
<secondary>Men's~~Socks~~Men's</secondary>
</category>
<URL>
<product>
http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=D*rqD2paIXY&offerid=191965.15115&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sunspel.com%2Fuk%2Fmens-cotton-socks-navy-stripes.html
</product>
<productImage>
http://www.sunspel.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/5/1588-236-new.jpg
</productImage>
</URL>
<description>
<short>
Our new cotton socks are designed by Sunspel and crafted in an Italian factory steeped in years of experience, skill and heritage. They are made from the highest quality, extra-long staple Egyptian cotton yarn which, prior to knitting is combed, twisted and mercerised to enhance the comfort, shine and absorption of the fabric as well as its resistance to pilling and shrinking.
</short>
</description>
<discount currency="GBP">
<type>amount</type>
</discount>
<price currency="GBP">
<retail>17.00</retail>
</price>
<shipping>
<availability>in-stock</availability>
</shipping>
<pixel>
http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=D*rqD2paIXY&bids=191965.15115&type=15&subid=0
</pixel>
</product>



<product product_id="15116" name="Cotton Socks" sku_number="1589/711">
<category>
<primary>Accessories</primary>
<secondary>Men's~~Socks~~Men's</secondary>
</category>
<URL>
<product>
http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=D*rqD2paIXY&offerid=191965.15116&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sunspel.com%2Fuk%2Fmens-cotton-socks-charcoal-melange-stripes.html
</product>
<productImage>
http://www.sunspel.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/5/1588-711-new.jpg
</productImage>
</URL>
<description>
<short>
Our new cotton socks are designed by Sunspel and crafted in an Italian factory steeped in years of experience, skill and heritage. They are made from the highest quality, extra-long staple Egyptian cotton yarn which, prior to knitting is combed, twisted and mercerised to enhance the comfort, shine and absorption of the fabric as well as its resistance to pilling and shrinking.
</short>
</description>
<discount currency="GBP">
<type>amount</type>
</discount>
<price currency="GBP">
<retail>17.00</retail>
</price>
<shipping>
<availability>in-stock</availability>
</shipping>
<pixel>
http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=D*rqD2paIXY&bids=191965.15116&type=15&subid=0
</pixel>
</product>
```

With some foreach statements I'm able to append all product children and attributes, but this doesn't actually give me the child data.

```
    $file1 = '35928_3210820_mp.xml';
$file2 = '39153_3210820_mp.xml';
$fileout = 'ukmerge.xml';
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file( $file1 );
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file( $file2 );  // loop through the product and add them and their attributes to xml1
$product = $xml2->product;
$prod = $xml2->merchandiser->header->product;
$category = $product->category;
$url = $product->URL;
$description = $product->description;
foreach( $xml2->children() as $child ) {
    $new = $xml1->addChild( $child->getName() , htmlspecialchars($child) );
    foreach( $child->attributes() as $key => $value ) {
        $new->addAttribute( $key, $value );

        }
    }   $fh = fopen( $fileout, 'w') or die ( "can't open file $fileout" );
fwrite( $fh, $xml1->asXML() );
fclose( $fh );
```

When I try to add on from there then everything gets messed up and nothing is in the correct place/order anymore. I'd also like to put this into a function since I'm going to be doing it often. Any help is greatly appreciate as I've been struggling with this for a few days now and have scowered over a few dozen stackoverflow and php.net threads.

One of the things that's confusing me is the `<merchandiser>` and `<header>` tags that every file starts with. Once the merchandiser tag ends it is the end of the document so I need to take only what's inside the merchandiser tag of file 2 and append it inside the merchandiser tag of file 1. The header tag just confuses me cause I'm not sure if it's gets in the way or not.

Comment: DOM can do this with `importNode()`

Comment: I have a script that I was trying to adapt earlier that used `importNode()` but it kept throwing a lot of errors. I'm very new to coding so small errors take me days to fix properly so I'd prefer to adapt the above code rather than start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As preliminary note, your XML sample is malformed. Also it is not coherent with your code (i.e. there is not `->merchandiser->header->product` ).

So, in this example I will use a different sample, like this one (*file1.xml*):

```
<root>
    <product>
        <name>Product 1</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product 2</name>
    </product>
</root>
```

and this one (*file2.xml*):

```
<root>
    <product>
        <name>Product 3</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product 4</name>
    </product>
</root>
```

You don't want to use `DOMDocument->importNode()` due “it kept throwing a lot of errors”.

You can use `DOMDocument` in conjunction with `SimpleXML` and `dom_import_simplexml()` function.

First of all, prepare destination XML: load the file with `SimpleXML`, create a `DOMDocument` using `dom_import_simplexml()` and set `$parent` variable to `<root>` element:

```
$dst = simplexml_load_file( 'file1.xml' );
$dst = dom_import_simplexml( $dst )->ownerDocument;
$parent = $dst->getElementsByTagName( 'root' )->item(0);
```

Then, load second file with `SimpleXML`:

```
$src = simplexml_load_file( 'file2.xml' );
```

Through a `foreach()` loop, import each `<product>` element from `SimpleXML` to `DOMDocument` and appent it as child of `$parent` node:

```
foreach( $src->product as $product )
{
    $node = dom_import_simplexml( $product );
    $node = $dst->importNode( $node, 1 );
    $parent->appendChild( $node );
}
```

Now, your merged XML is ready. You can print it using `$dst->saveXML()`.

I've not be able to product a correctly indented XML. BTW to do this, you can reload-it:

```
$final = new DOMDocument();
$final->loadXML( $dst->saveXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$final->formatOutput = True;
echo $final->saveXML();
```

Final output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 3</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 4</name>
  </product>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this right now. I wasn't sure if merchandiser was included or not and I've added a link to an XML file for now so that you can see the structure better. I'm not sure why it didn't show correctly the first time. http://gohuh.com/lsh/uk/35928_3210820_mp.xml

Am I replacing 'root' with 'merchandiser' ?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I was able to get this working correctly. Conceptually speaking what would be the best way for me to loop this so that I could combine a dozen XML files into one?

Comment: Conceptually, I think through a global `foreach`: you modify original file, so there is no reason to preserve original destination file.

Comment: Thanks! This will be my next journey.